# Inconsistent execution of php code in a simple calculator?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Php Calculator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="calculator">
      <form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
            <input type="text" name="display" id="display"><br>
            <button type="button" onclick="addToDisplay('7')">7</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="addToDisplay('8')">8</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="addToDisplay('9')">9</button>
               ....etc.
          </form>
    </div>
        <?php
       if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
         $expression = $_POST["display"];
         $expression = preg_replace('/[^0-9+\-*.\/\^\(\)\s]/', '', $expression);
         if (!empty($expression)) {
            eval("\$result = ($expression);");
          }
       }
           else{
            $result="";
       }
           echo "<script>resultDisplay();</script>";
    ?>
  
  </body>
  <script>
//Add terms to display
        function addToDisplay(value) {
            document.getElementById("display").value += value;
        }
// Clear the display
        function clearDisplay() {
            document.getElementById("display").value = null;
    }
    function resultDisplay() {
      var result = "<?php echo $result; ?>";
      document.getElementById("display").value = result;
    }
</html>


        
    </script>
```

I am new to php, and I tried to program a simple calculator. However, the calculator only occasionally displays the result from the php section, though when it does the math is correct.

I've messed around with how it tries to display the result but it's always inconsistent; invariably it will print nothing now and then. Does it have to do with the page loading? Even if so, I do not know how to fix it. I also tried echoing it directly as text outside the display as a test, but the result only appeared for a frame or two if at all.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, and it sounds oddly intermittent. You might try simplifying by outputting the result from PHP directly into the input, rather than using JavaScript.

Comment: Why this weird mix of PHP and JavaScript in the first place? When are you actually _submitting_ this form? All I see is click buttons that call a JS function, so I can't see how this was supposed to submit anything to the server side at all.

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies in the invocation of the resultDisplay() function. In the script, it is placed above its definition, and as we know, JavaScript is a programming language that operates synchronously, which means that the code is executed line by line, which is why the error occurs: caught ReferenceError: resultDisplay is not defined.

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
        $expression = $_POST["display"];
        $expression = preg_replace('/[^0-9+\-*.\/\^\(\)\s]/', '', $expression);
        if (!empty($expression)) {
            eval("\$result = ($expression);");
        }
    }
    else {
        $result="";
    }
    //transferred from here
?>

<script>
    function addToDisplay(value) {
        document.getElementById("display").value += value;
    }

    function clearDisplay() {
        document.getElementById("display").value = "";
    }

    function resultDisplay() {
        var result = "<?php echo $result; ?>";
        console.log(result);
        document.getElementById("display").value = result;
    }
    // into this place
    resultDisplay();
</script>
```